# How to update database with Entity Framework and SQL Server on remote host

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a SQL Server database on a remote web host provider. I want to update the database (with `add-migration` and `update-database` commands for package manager) on the remote host.

But the host does not provide remote access.

How can I update the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion database initializer to have the application update on startup.

> **Automatically Upgrading on Application Startup**
>
> If you are deploying your application you may want it to automatically
> upgrade the database (by applying any pending migrations) when the
> application launches. You can do this by registering the
> MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion database initializer

[Entity Framework Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx)

Or you can use update-database to generate a SQL script that will perform the upgrade. See [Entity Framework Code First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx) .  Then have your application somehow run that script.